# Would someone explain to me why type(foo)(bar) is so heavily discouraged?

Tags: python, types, user-input

I have a dict of configuration variables that looks something like this:

```
self.config = {
    "foo": "abcdef",
    "bar": 42,
    "xyz": True
}
```

I want to be able to update these variables from user input (which, in this case, will always be in the form of a string). The problem I'm facing is obvious, and my first solution seemed good enough to me:

```
def updateconfig(self, key, value):
    if key in self.config:
        self.config[key] = type(self.config[key])(value)
```

However, #python in Freenode almost seemed *offended* that I would suggest such a solution. Could someone tell me why this is bad practice?

Comment: Really strange code... Could you explain meaning semantics of type(self.config[key])?

Comment: I mean, this code doesn't imply any semantic relation between _key_'s type and target type of value!

Comment: It looks up the original type of the variable (which is undoubtedly correct) and sets the incoming value to that type. A better way of representing it might have been `old_value = self.config[key]` followed by `self.config[key] = type(old_value)(value)`.

Comment: oh, the type of value for the given key is invariant.. Got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all types support the idiom "call the type with a string to make a new instance of that type".  However, if you ensure you **only** have such types in your config dict (with a sanity check at init time maybe), **and** put suitable `try`/`except` protection around your conversion attempt (to deal with user errors such as typos in a **far** better way than dying with a stack trace would be;-), there's nothing "inherently wrong" in using that functionality for the types that do support it.

Comment: +1 discouraging use of language features seems too prevalent in python. It's like people want a weaker language.

Comment: `bool("False") -> True` is a type where this doesn't quite work.

Comment: @THCk, `type(True)(False) -> False` which is closer to the use case.

Comment: @THC4K, yep, good example. Among the 27 non-exception built-in types, the "really good ones" (where `repr(type(x)(repr(x)) == repr(x)`) are just float, long, int, complex -- str will be OK for the OP's case too (since it's not really `repr` that he's using, but an arbitrary string;-), unicode will be only with limitations (ASCII chars only!). Worst will be ones line bool, tuple, set, list, which _look_ like they'll work in that they'll raise no exception... but will perform weirdly (unless, in the containers' case, you **do** want containers with single-char items only;-).

Comment: @aaron (2nd cmt), **what**?!  The OP **does** say that the input "is always in the form of a string" -- your "closer to the use case" example is therefore not close at all!  (1st cmt) there are features , such as sufficiently-deep introspection, that are there solely to ease writing (e.g.) thorough tests / debuggers / IDEs in Python itself, and **should** be discouraged for use in **production** code. `type(x)(y)` (for the right, small set of types, able to "properly" build instances from a string: numbers and strings). The right string can be non-obvious (`''` is *the* way to say `False`!-).

Answer (score 0):

Not to mention, that there is config module in Python, here is how I would deal with config, with example of integer value "bar". +1 for alex as '' for the way to say False, see value "xyz"!

```
config = {
    "foo": "abcdef",
    "bar": "42",
    "xyz": "True" ## or 'Yes' or anything not False, "" for False
}

bar = ''
while not bar:
    barinput = raw_input('Enter property  bar, integer (1..99): ')
    try:
        if 0 < int(barinput) < 100:
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError("%s is not integer in range 1..99" % barinput)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(str(e)+"\nWrong input, try again")
    else:
        print("Saving correct value")
        bar = config["bar"] = barinput
print('New value of "bar" in config: %i' % int(config["bar"]))
```

The value could be saved as int in config also, but we have not need for `type` as we know that we are inputing integer.